Real world application of unweighted undirected pseudograph
In my this discrete math textbook, question 10.2 (page 430) asks for a real-world application for an unweighted undirected pseudograph. I assumed they also want you to have an edge that begins and ends at the same vertex in this application. I sat on this question for 15 minutes and asked others, but I was never able to come to a satisfying answer. I thought about finite state machines, but those are typically directed. If you had a road map, where intersections are vertices, you could view a parking garage as an edge that connects back to itself (most parking garages have only 1 entrance/exit, and you could view that as an intersection). Usually road maps are weighted and directed, though. The book's answer is also unsatisfying and bad, in my opinion.

Representing
connections on a social media app, where it is assumed that being connected is two-way (e.g. on
Facebook when you are friends versus on Instagram where following is one-way), and where you
are allows to connect to yourself (I actually do not know of a social media site that allows this, but
I suppose it is possible).

Is there any useful application for this type of graph?

Usefulness is relate. Coming back to the first article in graph theory, Euler's paper about Königsberg's bridges, we see that pseudograph is suitable there. That is question whether we can pass every bridge exactly once doesn't contradict the existence of bridge going to the same bank (or the same island). Such bridges are rare, but they exist, e. g. Molenbrücke in Dresden.
Eulerian path problem arises also in shopping mall planning. I. e., in the question whether there exist a walk that visits every shop once we may consider every branching point as a vertex and every corridor as an edge. (Similar to Chinese postman problem.) Some corridors however may end at the same point where they start.

It's a bit harder to imagine a scenario, though, where a pseudograph is appropriate but a pseudo-multigraph (in this textbook's terminology) is not: where we have loops but not parallel edges. I don't think that's true in most Eulerian path problems.

@MishaLavrov you are right. Even the original Euler's problem of seven bridges was about multigraph. However if we consider a problem on certain graph rather than the generalized problem, then such problems on pseudographs exist
